# Сell formatting not handled in macro (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

If enter only numbers or letters in a cell, then the formatting of the cell is not processed on them.

**For example**: when enter `333`, the numbers are shifted to the right. If enter the letters `hnm`, the letters are not aligned to the center of the cell - no formatting occurs either. Also, if enter `1m hnm`, `12m hnm`, `1234m hnm`, etc. - No conversion takes place.

I have this macro:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim numberformat As String
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim rng As Range, v As Variant
    For Each rng In Target
        'Worksheet Trim removes leading and trailing spaces and additional internal spaces
        rng = WorksheetFunction.Trim(rng)
        v = Split(rng, " ")
        'Skip any cell with more than two terms but still process remaining targets
        If UBound(v) = 1 Then
            If Len(v(0)) = 4 And IsNumeric(Left(v(0), 3)) And UCase(Right(v(0), 1)) = "M" Then
                rng = Trim(v(1) & " " & v(0))
            End If
            With rng
                .numberformat = "@"
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With rng.Font
                .Name = "Calibri"
                .Size = 11
            End With
        End If
    Next rng

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This macro converts the data in column A to **(any number)m** and **(any number)M** on the right.

For example:

```
L3 280M
500m FMA
Nest 475m
340m Pr6
720M uT10
345m RLM
etc.
```

Convert to:

```
L3 280M
FMA 500m
Nest 475m
Pr6 340m
uT10 720M
RLM 345m
etc.
```

Comment: I cannot get you, even try reading your question twice... You clearly say what is not good (no conversion), but you **do not explain IN WORDS what are your expectation against the code you show**. Your above code should do exactly what you show after "Convert to:". **What else do you want it doing**?

Comment: Move the `With rng` blocks down outside of the `If UBound(v) = 1 Then` statement so that the cell is always formatted.

Comment: @PeterT
Thank you! I moved the `With rng` blocks above the `If UBound(v) = 1 Then`. So works for me. But if enter `1m hnm`, `12m hnm`, `1234m hnm`, etc., the conversion still doesn't happen.

Comment: You are checking the length of the term and only converting if the length=4. You'll have to change that rule to convert other terms

Comment: @PeterT
Could you send me the full code or a piece of code where this should be edit/add?

Comment: Just change your If statement to something like `If IsNumeric(Left(v(0), 1)) And UCase(Right(v(0), 1)) = "M" Then`. This checks to see if the term begins with a number and ends with the letter "M", the term itself can be any length.

Comment: @PeterT
Thank you! Can I ask you one more question? Now I noticed that if enter `oct20`, then the conversion to `44854`. If enter `aug21`, then the conversion to `44794`. How can fix it?

Comment: Excel is performing an automatic conversion of a string it believes to be a date into a numerical date value. Change the format of the cell to Text and it will stay as `oct20`.

Comment: @PeterT Why doesn't it happen in other columns, Excel does not automatically convert? The conversion only happens in column A (where the macro works). I have `With rng .numberformat = "@"` in my macro, but `oct20` is converted to `44854`.

Comment: The conversion is happening *before* you apply the number format, as indicated in your code. Move the formatting of the cell up before you set the value and that should fix it.

Comment: @PeterT
I have tried pasting`numberformat="@"` in different places. But the problem doesn't go away. Even like this: `rng = WorksheetFunction.Trim(rng) With rng .numberformat="@"  v = Split(rng, "")`. As I understand it, this is due to `rng = WorksheetFunction.Trim(rng)`. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @PeterT
Many thanks. Understood. I moved `.numberformat = "@"` to `For Each rng In Target With rng .numberformat = "@" End With`. Now it works great!